# How can I refer id in add_widget()

Tags: python, kivy

I have a self-defined class like this,

in.kv,

```
<ProductButton>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        padding: 10, 10, 10, 10 
        Image:
            id: image1
            source: 
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: 20, 20, 20, 20 
            Label:
                id: label1
                text: 
            Label:
                id: label2
                text:
```

In .py, I am going to add ProductButton in a screen.

```
class ProductButton(ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    pass

class ProductPage(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        global real_result

        for x in range(len(real_result)):
            self.ids.box.add_widget(ProductButton())
```

I want to change the image and text of labels according to different x and I failed.
I have tried `self.ids.box.add_widget(ProductButton(self.ids.image1.source="123.png"))` and the error I got is `keyword can't be an expression`

I have also tried

```
product_button = ProductButton()
image1 = product_button.ids.image1.source
for x in range(len(real_result)):
    self.ids.box.add_widget(ProductButton(image1="123.png"))
```

and I got 
`TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`

I want to change the image and texts by referring ids in .py file. How?

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried `self.ids.box.add_widget(ProductButton(self.ids.image1.source="123.png"))` and the error I got is keyword can't be an expression

This is a straightforward Python syntax error: keywords can't be python expressions like `self.ids.image1.source`.

> `self.ids.box.add_widget(ProductButton(image1="123.png"))`
>
> and I got TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

This is probably because your class doesn't do anything with the `image1` keyword argument, and so passes it up to the `super` call, which eventually crashes when it gets to the top level `object` which doesn't expect an argument of this name.

It sounds like you want set the source of the image1 id within your new ProductButton. Do something like `your_object = ProductButton(); your_object.ids.image1.source = "123.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know how classes work to use Kivy properly. You tried to send arguments to class constructor which you haven't defined. Try this:

```
class ProductPage(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        global real_result

        for x in range(len(real_result)):
            self.productbutton = ProductButton()
            self.productbutton.ids.image1.source="123.png"
            self.ids.box.add_widget(self.productbutton)
```